# Does OpenLayers 3 support WCS?

Tags: openlayers, wcs

I was wondering if it is possible to display a map in ol3, which is constructed as WCS in MapServer/GeoServer?

Comment: As is evident in the comments on one answer the question in the title is different from what is asked in the question body, confusing the two answerers as to what was being asked.  Consequently, it is asking two questions which makes this too broad for focused Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Layers configured using WCS service are exposed through WMS service. At least in geoserver is that way. So you may configure your layer like any other wms layer.

```
new ol.layer.Image({
    extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
  })
```

Comment: No probs. glad to help

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question about WCS support.  The output of a WCS and a WMS are different, so whilst you can expose some coverage data through a WMS, you aren't getting access to raw coverage data, which is what a WCS gives you.

Comment: He only wanted to display a WCS layer using geoserver. This can be achieved using WMS service from geoserver (doc here ---> http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wcs/reference.html#introduction).  By the way if you have a better answer why dont you provide it???????? It would be much more helpful for the people reading

Comment: The title of the question is does OpenLayers 3 support WCS

Comment: There is no mention of layer in the question.  There is no concept of layer in WCS.  Using WMS to provide access to coverage data is a workaround at best.

Comment: You are missing the ol3 part mate. To display a map in ol3 you need a layer.

Comment: `To display a map in ol3 you need a layer` Yes, that's correct, which is probably why there's no in built support for coverage services in OpenLayers;  the two models don't fit very well.

Comment: I think there is no need for arguing. This question is two years old. User made the question was very happy with the answer. By the time of answering even the title was different. After all I prefer to answer to the questions and not on titles. Your purpose is to prove that ol3 do not support WCS which is totally out of scope of the question.

Comment: OpenLayers (2/3/4) doesn't support WCS, I don't think I have to prove it.  If you want to use WCS in a client using OpenLayers you have to write your own code.   If you just want to show an image, sure use WMS, but in that case why set up a WCS.

Comment: Thats the problem you just have to answer the question. Questions need answers while titles need .......????? what really????. It is as simple as that. To answer your question you need WCS on the server side if you want to create an image moscaic for example. So how would expose this layer on ol3??? using WMS is the only way to do it, unless you have a better solution which I will be very happy to hear about it.

Comment: But WCS is much more than mosaics of images. Lets's say you have multi-band images (more than 4 say)  and you want users to choose which bands to show and in which order.  You just can't perform this through WMS or WMS +SLD.  Let's say you have coverages of 3+ dimensions, you can create a 2D image by doing a sub-setting/trimming in WCS, but you can't do this with WMS.

Comment: Man he doesnt ask for full WCS support . He just want to display an image. This is waste of time... sorry

Comment: @nmtoken Such hair splitting. OpenLayers uses a "layer" as the basic build block of creating a map; it doesn't matter if WCS has a concept of layers or not. Answers don't have to directly answer the title question as written; they can provide *a different approach* that bypasses the question entirely. This is not only valid but encouraged on SE. This answer is plenty useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Does OpenLayers 3 support WCS?

No, there is no built-in support for WCS in OpenLayers of any version.

If you are the service/data provider and your coverage data is 2-D, you could consider a work around of also supplying a WMS of your data.  If you are not the service provider and you only have a WCS endpoint to consume, then you will have to roll your own code. Similarly if you have a multi-dimensional coverage and you want to provide 2-D data.

For example here's an example of a GeoServer WCS being consumed by OpenLayers 2:

http://ogcdev.bgs.ac.uk/ogcclient/WCS/GetCoverage_v2_0_1.html
[image: WCS 2.0.1 being accessed through OL-2]

Comment: He doesnt ask for WCS support for ol3. He wants to display a WCS layer in ol3. Better read the question again.