# Publish rasters in PostGIS into ArcGIS Server

Tags: postgis, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, .net

**Background**
I have a lot of, I mean a lot of rasters (GeoTiffs, around 10000) stored in a PostgreGIS database. I have developed a website and I want to allow users to extract a raster based on its storage date and display it on a base map. The following image is expressing an example of what I wan to do.
[image: GeoTiff on an OSM map]

I have used ArcGIS for Server 10.2, PostgreSQL 9.2, Windows 7 Ultimate, OpenLayers, and back-end is written in ASP.net MVC.

Should I automatically publish each raster as a map service once user extracts his/her required raster?

Comment: Best route would be to set up a WMS or WCS service., not sure you would need to write anything in .NET should be out of the box functionality in ArcGIS server (or you could substitute GeoServer, Mapserver, Rasdaman).  You can consume those services in Desktop clients/web clients. WMS out of the box, and WCS with a little JS coding.

Comment: `Should I automatically publish each raster as a map service` No publish all rasters as part of a  single service.  Let the WMS/WFS query handle which raster is provided to the user

Comment: @nmtoken you mean that I should publish a WMS service containing all the rasters? When I pass the wms to openlayers, all the rasters are displaying.

Comment: A WCS would probably be better, but in principle it would be theoretically possible to show all rasters if you didn't apply some scale layering, or other restrictions

Comment: @nmtoken can I handle to show only one of the rasters? I dont want to load all the rasters on the basemap. Only one or two rasters.

Comment: What you show as a base map in a web client is up to you

Comment: ArcGIS does not support PostGIS rasters. Even though they were geoTIFF before the were loaded, they aren't geoTIFF in the database (unless you just referenced the path in a raster dataset or managed catalog). ArcGIS 10.2 is old enough that you should be using 10.2.2 with at least a score of patches. Your title and question are not in agreement; I don't see any role for ArcGIS in your solution.

Comment: @nmtoken can I display and query the data of WCS service with openlayers?

Comment: @Vince when u want to create a wms or wfs service in arcgis server, you have to read data from the database, share it as a service and then create the service. this sharing process is conducting in arcgis software (arc map or arc catalog). I want to know if I should generate multiple services for each raster in my database based on the background I shared.

Comment: You will need to do your own coding to include WCS in OpenLayers, for example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166868/does-openlayers-3-support-wcs

Comment: Your post is unclear because you reference both OpenLayers and ArcGIS Server, and geoTIFF and database rasters when they cannot coexist in the manner you suggest. You should not post comments on your own post; instead [Edit] the question to make clarifications.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: @Vince honestly, I dont follow u. I have geoTiffs to be imported to my postgis database. then I want to publish a WMS service to display the rasters stored in my database using arcgis server. finally I want to use Openlayers to show this map service in my web page. Here simply I asked for a strategy based on my requirements and people are answering.

Comment: Other than ArcGIS not supporting PostGIS rasters, and rasters in databases effectively deprecated, and PostgreSQL support not being adequate for production use at 10.2, and the impossibility of running 1k services much less 10k on a single Server site, I can't see anything wrong with your plan. If the question were clearly written it could be closed for being too broad.

Comment: can we add st_raster arcgis library to postgis library and read postgis rasters? @Vince

Comment: No, st_raster is a completely different raster library. It does not read PostGIS rasters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is add layer time-aware in map meaning that time must be enabled for the underlying raster dataset. Because the image service is time-aware you can use the TimeSlider to view changes in the image over time, filter image ect use api js Esri:
http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/serving-time-aware-layers.htm
publish an image service
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/image_timeimageservice.html

Comment: Thank u @nicogis . do I have to use arcgis javascript api? or can I use openlayers?

Comment: I advise arcgis api js because allows you to work with an image map service directly. You have also 3D.